# Show that polynomial with non-zero constant term of nilpotent matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-equations, nilpotence

So I got a polynomial: $f(x) = a_nx^n+...+a_1x^1+a_0$ and $a_0  \neq  0$

And a matrix $A$ such that $A^k = 0$ for some $k$. I have to prove that $f(A)$ is invertible.

So, I know there is a fact that $E+A$ and $E-A$ are both invertible if $A$ is nilpotent and I'am trying to use that by computing $(E+A)^n$ and getting polynomial $g(A)$ but I am stuck here in attempts to connect $g(A)$ and $f(A)$

Comment: I guess $x_n=x^n$? And what's $E$?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true for $A = 0$. Missing some conditions?

Comment: @parsiad It's _obvious_ for $A=0$.

Comment: @Gae.S., E is identity matrix, and yes, sorry I've corrected polynomial (made typos)

Comment: Do you know anything about the eigenvalues of $f(A)$ in general, in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Woops, $a_0 \neq 0$. I see.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, this task doesn't  require knowledge of eigenvalues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $f(A)=a_0(E+A\cdot(\dots))$, and $A\cdot(\dots)$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it